# Bootstrap custom contents

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to get the custom content in bootstrap to look like this 
[image]

However, the div which holds the black background overflow the parent div.

Here is the code :

```
<div class="thumbnail shadow">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" style="background-color:black">
                        <h3 style="color: white">Purchase Order</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="caption">
                    <h3>3</h3>
                    <p>...</p>
                    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">View</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Please see http://www.bootply.com/OO8elZZx5j

-Alan-

Comment: not to be (fill with mean word) but it looks nice with the overflow :)

Answer (score 0):

The overflow is because you have a background on a column inside a `.row` class. (`.row` by default gives negative margins, which is offset by `col-xx-xx` giving equivalent padding).

Either remove the margins by overriding them on the row:

```
.shadow > .row {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

Or (preferably), give the target element a left margin and less width:

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" style="background-color:black; margin-left: 15px; width: 90%;">
  <h3 style="color: white">Purchase Order</h3>
</div>
```

I've created a new fiddle showcasing this [here](http://www.bootply.com/tPsUHuxaLf).

However, you really don't need a row **within** each column in this situation. What you should be doing is simply having a regular DIV within the outer column to handle the header (with the background), and another div to handle the body. The best way to handle this would be:

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
  <div class="thumbnail shadow">
    <div class="header">
      <h3 style="color: white">Purchase Order</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="caption">
      <h3>3</h3>
      <p>...</p>
      <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">View</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This will automatically handle the widths. Then you can just style `.header` to include the background, and automatically handle margins if you want to 'bring the headers out more':

```
.header {
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 5px;
  //margin-left: -5px;
  //margin-right: -5px;
}
```

I've created a *new* fiddle showcasing this [here](http://www.bootply.com/eqw8fI0h10).

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, the black background doesn't match the width correctly. And also is there any to have the fix size of the custom content? Because I am noticing the custom content's width increases as we add contents.

Comment: Ultimately, there's really no need to have nested rows within columns. I'll update my answer now to cover a much more 'elegant' solution to fix the background. Also, by `custom content` do you mean the text within the boxes? Like 'Thumbnail Label'?